# Where should I locate MIP and NLP solvers executables when using mindtpy with pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, ipopt

I am currently learning how to use pyomo on my own and I need to solve a MINLP problem with Open Solvers. I recently found I can use mindtpy, but I can't find the way to make it work because it can not locate the executables for the solvers.

I have declared my model, but when calling to solve it:

```
results = SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model, 
                                            mip_solver = 'glpk',  
                                            nlp_solver = 'ipopt', 
                                            )
```

I get the following error:

```
ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'
```

I have used pyomo to solve other MILP problems and I always specify the executable path for the solver so it can work, but I do not know how to specify the path for the executables in mindtpy or where pyomo is looking for the files.

How can I specify the path of the executables when using mindtpy ? Or how can I install the solvers in any other way that pyomo can find them on its own ?

Thank you !

I tried to include the path as an arguments for the mip and nlp solvers. It was a long shot but I needed to try whatever.

```
results = SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model, 
                                            mip_solver = 'glpk', 
                                            mip_solver_args = dict(executable = r'G:\Mi unidad\dev\winglpk-4.65\glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe', 
                                            nlp_solver = 'ipopt', 
                                            nlp_solver_args = dict(executable = r'G:\Mi unidad\dev\Ipopt-3.6.1-win64-icl10.1\Ipopt-3.6.1-win64-icl10.1\bin\ipopt.exe')
                                            )
```